# How to Make a Feed From User Submitted Posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-applications

I'm trying to figure out how to use AJAX to create a Twitter-like feed that displays user's posts on the same page immediately after they push the submit button. It would be an infinite-feed site that would have a "more" button at the bottom.

All I'm trying to make is a simple page containing a textarea box with a submit button and to have user submissions appear below the box as they are submitted.

If possible, a walk through or discussion of the script needed to do this would be great.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a server-side script with an SQL query that would return newer posts.
have your javascript store a variable of the date or of the last post id (used PHP for clarification):

```
result = mysql_query("SELECT ID,POST FROM POSTS WHERE DATE>" . $_GET['date']); //or use WHERE ID> $_GET['id']
while(rows[] = mysq_fetch_array(query));
print json_encode(rows);
```

now you have a server-side script that will return new posts, so all you have to do is write javascript function for the more button:

```
updatePosts = function () {
   $.ajax({
           url: 'serversiderUrl?lastId=' + last_id, //last_id is global variable for the id of the last post on the page
           success: function(data){
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                        for(i in data){
                            $('#posts_container').append(data[i].post); //do your appending functions here
                            last_id = data[i].id;
                         }
                     }
}
```

now for posting new entries create a server-side script of your favorite language that handles new posts:

```
result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO POSTS VALUES(''," . urldecode($_POST['POST']) . ")");
```

now for the client side:

```
submit_post = function(){
   $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url:'yourposturl',
           data: "post=" + encodeURIComponent($('#textArea').text()),
           success: function(){
                          updatePosts(); // call the function that update the posts so the new entry is now added to the page
                }
   });
}
```

Now bind the functions to the appropriate buttons when the document is fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#moreButtonId').click(updatePosts);
    $('#submitButtonId').click(submitPost);
});
```

Comment: Amjad, I really appreciate your comment. Just recently I rebuilt the website and I have a submit button. I know this sounds completely noobish of me to ask but how do I implement this code? I'm already grateful that you have written out all of the code for me, but I'm wondering 1) How do i create the javascript code that stores the last post id? I create a file with extension .js and write the necessary code into there? 2) Forpostingnew entries, what language would I use? HTML\JS? And lastly, are the client-side and server-side files separate? Do I have separate files besides the index.php? Ty

Comment: I've already added last_id var to the code in the success function of $.ajax, but u have to initialize it and to make it global just omit the "var" keyword when declaring the variable or use window.last_id. For the JS code you could place it in a separate .js file wherever you want in ur web root just reference it using a relative path from your HTML if your using one or embed it in the <head> part or you could print it all from your index.php (HTML + JS). As for posting new entries you could use the function above submit_post and bind it to the click event: $('buttonid').click(submit_post)

Comment: Ill try in the upcoming few days to quickly implement something to give you an idea, but meanwhile I suggest for you to do some reading and experimenting. But if you don't have the time try using a framework, e.g http://drupal.org/  http://www.joomla.org/ for it could simplify and take care of file structures and supply you with very useful functions and maybe you could find what your looking for in community contributions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways such as the submit button kept sending it to the database while we'd append text to a container underneath. Or we can update the container underneath to create a container (page) that are similar, after the ajax response is successful then we append the data to the container beneath

```
$.post(url,function(data){
    //Here you can append the data responsed by the ajax request to the container underneath
});
```

But you have to have a exactly same view with a conatiner (feed container) existing in the currently page